# AJAX Request from Chrome Extension on GoDaddy redirects it to different locale

Tags: ajax, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension which sends ajax requests to a website to check for broken links. However when I run this extension on websites like godaddy.com, the website gets redirected to a different locale. I am not sure whether this is happening for the AJAX request or due to some other reason. Can someone suggest something to get over this issue?

Comment: It seems your question is not that clear. Could you give more details like what does your code like and what do you mean "redirect to different locale", is that means the url you send ajax call to is redirected?

Comment: The thing is I have the chrome extension installed in the browser. Whenever a new website is opened, it uses ajax requests to check whether the links in the page are broken or not.. 
Now when I open www.godaddy.com, it automatically gets redirected to ar.godaddy.com or za.godaddy.com or some other domain instead of in.godaddy.com

Comment: But to be honest I am not sure this happens because of the ajax requests. Because, I start sending ajax requests only after the entire page is loaded. So, this really shouldn't happen.

Comment: you should know that when you type `www.godaddy.com` in the address bar and submit, the godaddy server will automatically redirect you to `ar.godaddy.com` or `za.godaddy.com` depending on your location.

Comment: Could you post some sample code for your question and tell us what is your  expect result and what is the actual result?